# RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted - Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm running a docker swarm using docker compose

and I'm trying to run tc in my script however it returns

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I double checked it and it seems I have to add some flags to my docker compose file.

I tried already adding

```
privileged: true
```

Which made no difference

and

```
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      capabilities:
        add: ["NET_ADMIN","NET_RAW"]
```

Which errored on starting up the swarm, I assume this is for kubernetes only.

Same for this option:

```
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

Has been added to the newest docker version and works fine with
Version: 20.10.5.

At least on Ubuntu 20 I had to update manually to the stable branch with the install script provided in the docker doc